# How can I validate certificate chain when CA certs held in Java Key Store

Tags: java, security, certificate, keytool, pki

Can someone please help me with the following, I googled before hand but did not find a blog outlining what I wanted to do, thanks in advance.

I have and internal test PKI (based on AD CS). I have imported the Root CA certificate and the Issuing CA Certificate (minus their private keys) into the CACerts java key store (keying the GUI tool "KeyStore Explorer 5.5.1"

I have a leaf (end-entity certificate) 'outside of the Java keystore' as I want to simulate a situation where the client would obtain (be given) the leaf certificate via a WEB browser (for example when opening a TLS connection to a WEB server).

The leaf certificate is stored in a .pem flat file on the same computer where it was create (using Windows default method so private key for the cert is in the Windows keyStore). The computer also contains the Java KeyStore CACerts (where I imported the CA certs as above) and the Java JDK (so Keytool.exe for example)

So what I need to do (ideally using Keytool or a pre-made script suitable for Windows) is point to the leaf .pem certificate and say go check the certificate chain of this leaf certificate but using the CA certs held in CACerts keystore

Can someone kindly tell me how to do this as the only examples I have seen this far are about checking the chain for certs already in the CACerts keystore. Whereas I want to check the chain of a .pem flat file against the CA certs held in the CACerts java keystore

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? Note that later versions of Java have switched to PKCS#12 for the key / trust stores.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes+ 'switched' is slightly overstating the case. Java 8 (since 2014) _supports_ PKCS12 as a file format (including for truststore) but defaults to JKS as lower versions did. Java 9 (2017) up _default_ to PKCS12, but continue to support JKS and JCEKS if you specify them when creating; when reading 9 up use a new API that adapts to any supported format. And up through 17 (including 17.0.3.1 last month) the Oracle-packaged cacerts is still JKS.

Comment: OP: you are not accurately 'simulating' a TLS connection; a TLS server is required to send the leaf cert AND any chain cert(s) (usually only one, but can be more) needed to validate, and a standard TLS client can and does validate using a truststore containing only the root cert(s), although browsers in particular often can fetch a missing chain cert if the child has valid AIA.caIssuer. In any case keytool doesn't do this (in any version), nor any other commandline tool I've heard of, and in any case _using_ programs (rather than developing them) is now considered offtopic for SO.

Comment: You could write a Java program to do this, using the CertPathValidator API, and that would be on-topic. However, it will treat all truststore certs, root or not, as anchors, and thus may not reject a cert that is actually invalid if you have an applicable chain cert in the truststore as well as the root.

Comment: Or try to convert to PKCS#12 with one of the many key store tools out there, and then use OpenSSL possibly.

Comment: Hello All 
Thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: Hello All

Thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my query

In my LAB I am using Java version 18.0.1.1 

My my case the client will be making an LDAPS connection to an Active Directory Domain Controller (rather than a WEB Server).

I wanted to confirm the certificate from the Domain Controller (which I have a copy of in PEM format). Can chain up OK to the CA certs (Root, and Issuing CA) held in the Java Key Store. I was hopping to use the command line to do this>
It works OK with OpenSSL but I have to copy the certs out of the Java Key Store first into a combined pem file